# Why isn't Image Resizer in 2SXC is not working

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, imageresizer

I am trying to use 2SXC with DNN and I can't get the Image Resize functions to work. Basically, they do nothing. I have installed a new DNN 9.12 portal, installed the 2SXC, and started working through the tutorials. 2SXC seems to work but the Image Resizer functionality isn't working at all.

Here is my Template and a screen shot showing the result:

```
@inherits Custom.Hybrid.Razor14
@{
  var imgUrl2 = @Content.Image.ToString();
}

<div class="row mb-4 mb- md-5" @Edit.TagToolbar(Content)>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-1" style="background: gray;">
        <img class="img-fluid" src='@Content.Image?w=50&h=50' alt="@Content.Name" />        
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 order-md-4">
        <h1>
            @Content.Name
        </h1>
        @Html.Raw(@Content.Description)
    </div>
</div>
@imgUrl2
<br>
<img loading="lazy" src="@Link.Image(url: imgUrl2, width: 200)">
```

***Here is the output HTML:***

```
    <div id="dnn_ctr386_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent Mod2sxcappC">
         <div class="sc-content-block" data-cb-instance="386" data-cb-id="386">
          <div class="row mb-4 mb- md-5">
           <div style="background: gray;" class="col-md-4 order-md-1">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="/portaldev/Portals/0/adam/BucketList/jKW1MSja7UiF1Fj0KQMfug/Image/20070411_005.jpg?w=50&amp;h=50" alt="Travel to Germany">        
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-8 order-md-4">
            <h1>
             Travel to Germany
            </h1>
            <ul>
             <li>Visit Hans</li>
             <li>Visit Neuschwanstein</li>
             <li>Ski the Zugspitze</li>
            </ul>
           </div>
          </div>
          /portaldev/Portals/0/adam/BucketList/jKW1MSja7UiF1Fj0KQMfug/Image/20070411_005.jpg
          <br>
          <img loading="lazy" src="/portaldev/Portals/0/adam/BucketList/jKW1MSja7UiF1Fj0KQMfug/Image/20070411_005.jpg?w=200">
         </div>
        </div>
```

Here is a screen grab showing the images not resizing correctly.
[image]

Comment: Would you be able to add to what you have provided above? What does the generated HTML source look like from the above screenshot?

Comment: @JeremyFarrance - thanks for taking a look. I have updated the post to include the HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure ImageFlow is active (vs. it's not working).

We just updated the docs to provide more in-depth information and guide you through this https://go.2sxc.org/resize.

Comment: Thanks for the info, lots of good information there. However, I am still stuck. I think I have determined that ImageFlow simply isn't running (processing my images). I started with a clean install of DNN 9.13 and the latest version of 2sxc 16.07. Web.config looks right and all the DLLs are where they should be. Etag in response header still has quotes around it - so I assume it isn't processing. Tried to manually install ImageFlow but the installed version is newer. Any more thoughts?

Comment: minor idea: do you have the C++ libraries installed? I think you need them... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76228647/issue-with-imageflow-image-resizing-on-production-server-using-oqtane-with-2sxc

Comment: I have C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable 14.36.32532 installed.  I am assuming it got loaded when I loaded VS2022 - not sure.

Comment: So for kicks and giggles, I removed C++ version 14.36 and installed 14.29. No change. Another thing I didn't mention earlier, I don't have the cache directory in my App_Data folder that you mention in the documentation... "check if you have a folder for the cached images and if it gets new files as you try different resize combinations (eg ?w=1000 v ?w=1001). -  in DNN / Oqtane check the folder [root]/App_Data/imageflow_hybrid_cache" I assume that is because ImageFlow isn't running. Got anything else? I've reached the limit of my expertise.

Comment: Just to clarify: you're trying to get it to run on a Windows 11 PC, correct? not a server. And it's a dev machine; you have VS 2022 installed.

Comment: Is it possible that you have restricted permissions on the folders? It could be that your IIS (and services in it) can't create folders etc. - which would prevent the image resizer from creating it's DB folder etc?

Comment: I highly suggest you a) check your windows Event logs (IIS will probably complain). Also turn on your Dnn logging to file and check what the file system reports. I'm pretty sure you'll find something to help you.

Comment: Again @iJungleBoy thanks for all the help. Yes - I am running on my development machine (Windows 10) and I have multiple version of VS installed (17,19, & 22). I have developed a few different DNN modules on this machine but this one has me stumped. I don't see any errors in DNN logs, event viewer, or IIS logs. In fact, I don't see anything about ImageFlow anywhere. I do see calls to /tosic_sexycontent/js/2sxc... resources but not ImageFlow. Is there a way to manually run the api call through a URL for testing? I am sure it is something simple I'm just missing it.

Comment: We are needing to upgrade our DNN site and I really want to use the structured content for several things. I think what you have built is really slick (or should I say sic!) but I'll be danged if I can get it to work.

Comment: So it must be something with your machine. Something we have never encountered before. I'm sure that in another VM, Server or Azure it would just work. I'm afraid this can't be resolved here. I recommend you get a VM or someone to help on your system directly with a lot of experience - eg. 2sxc.org/support.